# HttpWebRequest Connection Limit and RestFUL server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, social-networking

I have created a server product that is connecting to some social network servers and sending to data which status update etc. The server already authenticated to necessary social networks servers by users who is using this solution.

Actually, I have no problem at this time, but I think I will.

My server will be open a thousands of concurrent request to neccessary servers via Http with C# HttpWebRequest instance. I already know that It's possible to change concurrent request limits with below propery.

> ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit

AFAIK, this limit is max 100 evet you set more than 100.

So, I will be faced with bottleneck problem with HttpWebRequest even change the DefaultConnectionLimit  property of ServicePointManager.

I would like know you guys what are you thinking about this.
Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you really, absolutely, need all of those connections simultaneously? Even if you do, would you be able to process the responses adequately simultaneously?

Comment: How are you using the connections? Sync / Async

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring whether or not this is a good idea, have you tried using a unique ConnectionGroupName for each request, e.g. Guid.NewGuid().ToString()?  The connection limit is per connection group so this may help unless there is some global limit.  You should disable KeepAlive unless you will be reusing the group names for subsequent requests.  See my answer to [HttpWebRequest How to handle (premature) closure of underlying TCP connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390780/httpwebrequest-how-to-handle-premature-closure-of-underlying-tcp-connection/4446365#4446365).

Comment: Sounds good, Have you ever applied to stress tests to your idea ?

Comment: I haven't tried it with a large number of connections, but it does override the connection limit on a small scale.  This is mentioned in MSDN, and I've tried it as well.  MSDN: "Each connection group creates additional connections for a server. This may result in exceeding the number of connections set by the ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit property for that server."

Comment: This is the strategy used by System.Net.HttpClient also. Just for anyone, like me, who comes to this thread now.